NICE Fall 2021 problem
[NICE Fall 2021]

For each complex number $p$ not equal to $0$ or $1$, let $p'$ denote the complex number for which $1/p + 1/p' = 1$. There are precisely two complex numbers $p$ satisfying $(1/p)' = 1/p'$. What are they?

I can get $p^{'}=p/(p-1)$. Considering $p = a + bi, \: p^{'}= c + di$. And there are only two complex numbers. I'm lost.

Any attempts or ideas?

In the expression p′=p/(p−1)...（1）, replace p with 1/p, then you get (1/p)'=1/(1-p)...(2).
Replace (1/p)' and p' in  (1/p)′=1/p′ with the two equations, obtaining p²−p+1=0
Then use the quadratic formula to find the roots. The results will be consistent with the previous answer.

According to the question, 
$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$ and $p+p'=1$
Solving these two simultaneously gives, 
$p=-\omega,-\omega^2$
where $\omega=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$
